# Парсинг xsd-файла

Tags: python, xml, xsd

Есть задача по парсингу xsd-файла.

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Fujitsu Interstage XWand B0233 -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/ep/ep_ins_not_med_y_39" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ep_ins_not_med_y_39="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/ep/ep_ins_not_med_y_39" xmlns:FR_4_008_01a_08="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_01a_08" xmlns:FR_4_008_01a_07="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_01a_07" xmlns:ref="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/ref" xmlns:FR_2_004_01c_01="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_2_004_01c_01">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_02_08_39" schemaLocation="../tab/FR_4_008_02_08_39/FR_4_008_02_08_39.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_03_08_39" schemaLocation="../tab/FR_4_008_03_08_39/FR_4_008_03_08_39.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
```

Файл взят с сайта ЦБ РФ (содержимое пришлось сократить, ибо не влезал весь текст)

Когда я пытаюсь разобрать его с помощью модуля lxml, то могу дойти до атрибутов первого файла, но не могу перейти на вложенные файлы xsd.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Зачем вообще его парсить? это ведь схема для формирования манифеста.

Comment: парсил полгода назад.... там 2-3 библиотеки... 2 из них не смогли скушать схему 1с, а третью пришлось немного пропатчить. сейчас гуглится какие то другие модули)

Comment: @And чтоб оопно создавать сущности

Answer (score 0):

В lxml я не силен, но при помощи `xml.etree` из стандартной библиотеки можно очень просто достать xsd:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
my_xml="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Fujitsu Interstage XWand B0233 -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/ep/ep_ins_not_med_y_39" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ep_ins_not_med_y_39="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/ep/ep_ins_not_med_y_39" xmlns:FR_4_008_01a_08="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_01a_08" xmlns:FR_4_008_01a_07="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_01a_07" xmlns:ref="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/ref" xmlns:FR_2_004_01c_01="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_2_004_01c_01">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_02_08_39" schemaLocation="../tab/FR_4_008_02_08_39/FR_4_008_02_08_39.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-07-31/tab/FR_4_008_03_08_39" schemaLocation="../tab/FR_4_008_03_08_39/FR_4_008_03_08_39.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>"""


s = ET.fromstring(my_xml)
for k in s.iter():
   if 'schemaLocation' in k.attrib:
      print  k.attrib['schemaLocation']
```

Comment: ты тут тоже до атрибутов доходишь, а надо каким-то образом( не знаю каким) добраться до атрибутов вложенных файлов(допустим вот этого  '<xsd:import namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd"/>'. Эти файлы-схемы, так же заполнены и тд. мне надо их открыть. есть идеи?

Comment: Опишите более подробно что вам надо получить

Comment: вложенные xsd схемы, часть пути на которые прописан в sxhemaLocation, которые надо пропарсить и вытащить элементы(не xsd схемы)  ,если там есть xsd схемы парсить дальше, как-то так